# Sorting mysql value and select the top biggest value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called mydatabase.db and a table named mytable.
Inside my table there's row like this :

```
Name    A       B      C       D      E      F     G      H
Andy    1       2      3       4      5      6     7      7
```

I want to only select the value which is bigger than 5. In this case means F,G,H.
Any idea how?

Comment: you mean only select those columns ?

Comment: What is the name of the colums? I can't seem to understand how your table really looks like.

Comment: yes... so i want to select only the column which has the value bigger than 5 @lagbox

Comment: Try something like `SELECT column, COUNT(id) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY column HAVING COUNT(id) > 5` Or `select count(*) from
(
    select name
    from your_table
    group by column1, column2
    having count(*) > 5
) x`

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited it @Svenskunganka

Comment: Is `Name` and `Andy` your column names, or is it the letters themselves that are the column names? Your layout is confusing. @monsterchub

Comment: Name,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H are column names. The rest is the value. @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select 
 name ,
 max(case when A > 5 then A else 'null' end )as 'A',
 max(case when B > 5 then B else 'null' end )as 'B',
 max(case when C > 5 then C else 'null' end )as 'C',
 max(case when D > 5 then D else 'null' end )as 'D',
 max(case when E > 5 then E else 'null' end )as 'E',
 max(case when F > 5 then F else 'null' end )as 'F',
 max(case when G > 5 then G else 'null' end )as 'G',
 max(case when H > 5 then H else 'null' end )as 'H'

 FROM table1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01f3b/5)

and after you can just in php make condition if some column = 'null' then dont display it.

Comment: @xqbert :) it was ROM :) , i didnt mention it , thanks

Comment: I need to match with rules like "if A>5 AND B>5 AND C>5 THEN echo a,b,c >5". if A>5 AND C>5 AND D>5 THEN echo a,c,d>5". How can i do it? @echo_Me